# MVC Model Binding with Checkbox list....possibly haunted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, checkboxlist

I have a viewmodel with a list of objects which I'm rendering as checkboxes with the `MVC` `CheckboxFor()` helper like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OrganisationDetails.Industries[i].Checked)
```

When the HTML renders, I get the standard double output which all appears as it should be:

```
<input id="OrganisationDetails_Industries_0__Checked" name="OrganisationDetails.Industries[0].Checked" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="OrganisationDetails.Industries[0].Checked" type="hidden" value="false">
```

When I look at the HTTP headers that are posted, I see the values set correctly for the checkbox I've ticked:

```
OrganisationDetails.Industries[3].Checked:true
OrganisationDetails.Industries[3].Checked:false
```

However, when I get back into C# and examine the `model` parameter of the POST action which received the form, the value is always bound as false.

I'm aware of many many other questions which skirt around this issue, but most say that when the HTTP form values are posted as above, the model binder *should* handle it, in my case however it's not.

I've ensured there are no other fields on the form, no hiddens kicking about, no custom model binding configs etc etc.

Everything else in other areas of the form binds OK, just not the checkboxes.

Is it because they are nested in a child class? does the property `Checked` conflict with an HTML property during post? I'm serious stumped here and about to revert to not using the helper.

I'm posting here because I don't believe that the helper is fundamentally broken, so I'd like to understand what I've done wrong!

EDIT: Here is the model (abridged for brevity) and controller action if it's any help.

```
**model classes**

public class Industry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationDetails 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Industry", Description = "Select all that apply")]
    public List<Industry> Industries = new List<Industry>
    {
        new Industry { Id = 1, Name = "Industry 1" },
        new Industry { Id = 2, Name = "Industry 2" },
        new Industry { Id = 3, Name = "Industry 3" },
        new Industry { Id = 4, Name = "Industry 4" }
    };        
}


public class TheViewModel 
{
    public OrganisationDetails { get; set; }
}

**controller action**

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("OrganisationDetails/Part/{id}")]
    public ActionResult OrganisationDetails(int id, TheViewModel model)
    {
        // breakpoint is on this line, model.OrganisationDetails.Industries are all shown with 'Checked = false'
        // this is where I was about to write the persistance code, but the model values aren't correct for this collection, so there is nothing in here.
        return RedirectToAction($"OrganisationDetails/Part/{id + 1}");
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me that you're trying to set the "checked" property of OrganisationDetails.Industries[n], but what you're actually doing is setting the object OrganisationalDetails.Industries[m].checked to "true" (whatever that means.)

Comment: Well, the list of industry objects has a `Checked` property, so yes I'm trying to set that to true, which is what I want to persist after it's model bound

Comment: This generally should work.  Can you post the model and controller code?

Comment: What you have shown will work correctly. Show the model and controller code. The most common reason for not binding is that `Checked` is a field in your model, not a property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke interesting comment, can you clarify what you're meaning by the difference between the two? do you mean a field as is a private backing field vs a property as a public auto property?

Comment: @Duston I thought the field name might be confusing, if you imagine it says `Selected` does that clarify?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields. So it you had just `public bool Checked; (as opposed to public bool Checked { get; set; }`) then it would not bind

Comment: @StephenMuecke gotcha, yeah all the properties have auto getters/setters and are public, so it should be OK. I was wondering if it's having trouble as the properties are in a nested class in the ViewModel but I'm 99.9% sure I've used this kind of structure for large forms in the past without and problems

Comment: But `public List<Industry> Industries` is a field :) - its needs to be `public List<Industry> Industries { get; set; }` and you populate it in a parameter-less constructor

Comment: @StephenMuecke GAH! my hero! thanks! do you want to expand this to an answer for me to accept, or want me to?

Comment: Just duped it instead :)